# How to set HTML and CSS in your grape js editor?

Tags: grapesjs

I was working in grapesjs and just want to know is there a way to render the HTML and CSS saved in your DB to show inside the grapesJS editor.
I saved the HTML and CSS inside the DB and want to render the design inside the editor. is this possible to achieve this in grapesJs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found this solution. First, save your HTML and CSS inside variables. Then, do this.

```
editor.setComponents(html);
editor.setStyle(css);
```